# EF Core 3.1 query sometimes is superfast but sometimes is slow

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 3.1 with sql server 2019 Developer Edition
I have a complex select query with multiple includes which 90% percent is very fast (avg 200ms) but sometimes it becomes slow (sometimes takes up to 25 seconds) for the same parameters.

I have read about parameter sniffing in sql server but I don't know how to identify if this is the case that slows down the query.
How can I check if this is the case?

Comment: Is EF generating the SQL, or did you write custom SQL for this?

Comment: EF is generating the SQL. no custom code

Comment: Are you creating a new DataContext each time you query (or within the boundaries of an aggregate root)?

Comment: I am creating a new DbContext since it services a REST endpoint

Comment: And you're wrapping the DbContext in a `using` statement?

Comment: I am using Autofac and the DbContext is declared as InstancePerLifetimeScope

Comment: Are TCP/IP connections enabled?  https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Oct/26/Sql-Server-Slow-Connections-with-2-second-or-so-delay

Comment: It was disabled. I enabled it. Btw SQL Server is localhost not on a different machine than web server (VS2019)

Comment: Roger that. Rick Strahl claims the problem can be localized to the dev box.

Comment: And I've had these kinds of problems before, related to connections.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209851/discussion-between-pantonis-and-robert-harvey).

Comment: Is it possible in your architecture to move that complex query to SQL Stored Procedure ? SQL Server is caching and optimizing query execution plans better for procedures. Also it is possible to optimize query independent of the application code.

Comment: I cant unfortunately. I am using the same query for retrieving and updating using EF Core

Comment: @AlekseiSemidotskii: I doubt that would cause the kinds of delays described here.  It's almost certainly a connection problem.

Comment: I ran the sql profiler and I was able to capture it there when it was slow. Duration in SQL Server profiler is almost the same as the total time of the request logged by asp.net core logger. So I suppose this is not a connection problem.

Answer (score 3):

> I have read about parameter sniffing in sql server but I don't know how to identify if this is the case that slows down the query. How can I check if this is the case?

Turn on the SQL Server Query Store. [Monitoring performance by using the Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15)